# Recursive division within a class

Tags: python, oop, loops, recursion

I'm trying to practice OOP and recursion but I'm having some trouble.  I think the recursive aspects of it are correct but the way I'm structuring class is wrong.

**How it should work:**
It should subtract 1 from 6, until x = 0.  Each time adding 1 to index.  When x is equal to 0 the function should return index.

**Where I'm Getting Errors:**
The following code says I have an error because divide accepts three arguements while I've only supplied two.  But I thought that self wasn't really an argument.  It was just something that had to be done in a class.

How do I make the below code work as intended?

```
class Division(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.index = 0
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def divide(self, x, y):
        self.index += 1
        if self.x <= 0:
            return self.index
        return divide(self.x-self.y, self.y)

print(Division.divide(6,1))
```

**Edit (Revised Code):**
Now I'm getting an error that divide is not defined?

```
class Division(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.index = 0

    def divide(self, x, y):
        self.index += 1
        if x <= 0:
            return self.index
        return divide(x-y, y)

print(Division().divide(6,1))
```

**Second Edit:**
I think I figured it out.  I had to add create an instance of Division again on the divide methods recursive return.  My output is wrong though.  It's saying self.index is equal to one.  Probably because when I create a new instance of the class the index is set to 0.  How do I overcome this problem?

**Final Code:**

```
class Division(object):

        def __init__(self):
            self.index = 0

        def divide(self, x, y):
            self.index += 1
            if x <= y:
                return self.index
            return self.divide(x-y, y)

print(Division().divide(6,1))
```

Comment: `Division(1, 2).divide(6,1)`, you need to create an instance first.

Comment: Note that you are not using `x` and `y` in `divide` (not a root cause, just a hint to review the design).

Comment: you must call `self.divide` ... there is no global `divide` method ...

Comment: sidenote rule of thumb: when you have a class that has two methods, one of which is `__init__`, you shouldn't be using a class.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Thank you.  That got me my desired output.

Comment: @roippi: I think that's debatable. One obvious exception to the proposed rule is when you need to keep private state across the calls to the method.

Comment: @roippi Well, I did it more so to practice classes but you're right.  I probably didn't need a class.  I tried to do it with just a function but I couldn't get it to work.  I'll try it again without the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you want to have an object here... What does it models ? So here is a solution without object

```
def divide(a, b, q = 0):
    if a < b:
        return q
    return divide(a-b, b, q+1)
```